# Rails respond_to block fails in RSpec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, json, rspec, bdd

I have an action in a controller that uses the context of the currently logged in user and the nested route of the create action to produce a new join model relationship. The intended use of this is a `button_to ... remote: true` in the view.

### Controller

```
...
def create
    enrollment = Enrollment.new(course_id: params[:course_id], user_id: current_user)
    respond_to do |format|
        if enrollment.save
            format.json {...}
            format.html {...}
        else
            ...
        end
    end
end
```

### RSpec minus the blocks

I then attempt to ensure that this works in RSpec using the following. (Note: the user is logged in before the test)

```
let(:course) { FactoryGirl.create(:course) }
let(:user)   { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
...
post :create, course_id: course, :format => :json
post :create, {course_id: course, :format => :json}
xhr :post, :create, course_id: course, :format => :json
xhr :post, :create, course_id: course
```

Each of the attempts result in an ActionController::UnknownFormat being raised at the `respond_to`. This also happens in the tests for a regular http POST. I have looked at all the tutorials for testing JSON APIs with RSpec and nothing has got me past this error.

#### Additional Information / Attempts

I tried implementing this action with the default use of `js`, but results in the same error.

Here is the respective JSON attempt...

```
<form action="/courses/1/enrollments" class="button_to" data-remote="true" data-type="json" method="post"><div><input type="submit" value="Completed" /></div></form>
```

Rails log outputs

```
Processing by EnrollmentsController#Create as JSON # => or JS
```

Changing the route to have `defaults: { format: 'json' }` results in the same error...

```
Started POST "/courses/2/enrollments" for 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1
Processing by EnrollmentsController#create as JSON
Completed 406 Not Acceptable
ActionController::UnknownFormat
```

#### Setup:

- Rails 4.1
- JRuby 1.7.12

Comment: xhr usually have format `js`. And since your link/button `remote: true` it will have.

Comment: With the `button_to` I have added `form: {"data-type" => "json"}`, but I am directly testing the controller.

Comment: Is the recording saving ok? Perhaps the problem lies in the else block that you have omitted

Comment: The `#save` method never gets called. Execution halts at the `respond_to`.